# Flutter: build runner throws a precompile error

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

I am using `analyser` 1.7.1. The latest `build_runner` build command generates the following error.

> flutter packages pub run build_runner build Failed to precompile
> build_runner:build_runner:
> ../../../sdk/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/analyzer-1.7.1/lib/src/error/best_practices_verifier.dart:1998:14:
> Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type
> 'String' doesn't allow null.   String get displayString {

The usual `flutter clean` and `pub cache repair` commands don't seem to be fixing the problem, and `displayString` doesn't appear anywhere in my codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46337) open 9 days ago. Here's the key part:

> Right now, the current state of affairs is that:
>
> - package:analyzer 1.7.0 requires package:meta ^1.4.0
> - package:analyzer 1.7.1 has the same contents as 1.7.0, but requires package:meta ^1.3.0
> - Flutter stable pins package:meta to 1.3.0
>
> I'm uncertain how we're running into the exceptions above - the two most recent versions of analyzer are pretty explicit about which version of meta they need.
>
> @edlman do you have any dependency_overrides in your pubspec?

> you're right, I'm using 3rd party pkgs which depend on meta 1.4.0 so I put it to dependency_overrides to solve the collision. It didn't come to my mind it cause such a problem.
> I've changed the override to 1.3.0, it works fine, no problem yet

So I'd suggest checking whether or not there's a dependency_overrides in your pubspec, too.

Comment: Yes, I have `1.4.0` in my dependency overrides.

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with `analyser` 1.7.1.

Add

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: 1.7.0
```

to `pubspec.yaml`.

There are more details available in raina77ow's answer.